# React router not redirecting to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a main component, I have initialized a Router, which I want to redirect to the Login component, but when I go to http://localhost:3000/login  It doesn't show me the login component, It still shows the App.js, what may be the reason

**APP.JS**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import './styles.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import LoginComponent from './components/LoginComponent';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

class Apps extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Don't do this!
        this.state = {
            showing: true,
            Login: false,
            Signup: false,
            Members: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container" style={{ display: (this.state.showing ? 'block' : 'none') }}>
                  <div >A Single Page web application made with react</div>
                </div>
                <LoginComponent view={this.state.Login} />
                <div className="buttons">
                    <a href='' ref="login" onClick={this.Login_onclick.bind(this)} >{this.state.Login? "back": "Login"}</a>
                </div>
                <Router>
                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent}/>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }

    Login_onclick(e) {
        this.setState({Login: !this.state.Login });
        e.preventDefault(); //alert(e.target.value);
        this.setState({showing: !this.state.showing});
        // this.setState({ref: !ref});
    }
}

export default Apps;
```

**LoginComponent.js**

```
class LoginComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = ({details: {}});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // console.log('Component DID MOUNT!')
        this.ajaxloader();
    }

    ajaxloader() {
        fetch("./login.php")
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(
            (result) => {
              console.log(result);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="login" style={{ display: (this.props.view ? 'block' : 'none') }}>
                <h3>Login</h3><br/>
                Username: <input type="text" ref="username"/><br/>
                Password <input type="password" ref="password"/>
                <button value="Login" ref="login" >Login</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginComponent;
```

Comment: You need to wrap the routes in switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <Router>
  <switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent}/>
  </switch>
 </Router>
```

And make sure you import switch from *react-router-dom* as follow.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```